# SetTimeout and ClearTimeout (Doesn't clear at 0)

Tags: javascript

Maybe just sleep deprivation, but I can not understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm calling a `countDown` function `onLoad` with `setInterval`.

Inside the `countDown` function I call `clearTimeout` when the number reaches 0 except it's called when it reaches 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a snippet.

```js
var interval, count = 5;

countDown()
interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

function countDown() {
  document.body.innerHTML = count
  count--

  if(count === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    document.body.innerHTML = "Redirecting to ....."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countDown() {
  document.body.innerHTML = count;
  if(count === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    document.body.innerHTML = "Redirecting to .....";
  } else {
    count--;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll be able to accept in 4 minutes. God I feel dumb today. Last time I try coding off 3 days of no sleep.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are decreasing the counter first and then evaluating, due to this 1 step is missed

```js
var interval, count = 5;

countDown();
interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);


function countDown() {
  

  if(count === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    document.body.innerHTML = "Redirecting to ....."
  }
  else
  {
     document.body.innerHTML = count
     count--
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `count--` after the if statement, and a `return;` at the end of the if statement if you want to block the execution after that.

```js
var interval, count = 5;

countDown()
interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

function countDown() {
  document.body.innerHTML = count;
  

  if(count === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.body.innerHTML = "Redirecting to .....";
    return;
  }
  count--
}
```